# iOS html/xml parsing google shopping results with TFHpple

Tags: ios, parsing, tfhpple

is there any way to parsing google shopping results using TFHpple without using google API (deprecated) but simple using url like for example this: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbm=shop&q=AudiR8   ?

I've tried many types of tags:

```
...
myCar = @"Audi R8";
myURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbm=shop&q=%@",myCar];
NSData *htmlData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURL]];
TFHpple *xpath = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];
//use xpath to search element
NSArray *elements = [NSArray new];
elements = [xpath searchWithXPathQuery:@"//html//body"]; // <-- tags
...
```

but nothing to do, always the same output console message: UNABLE TO PARSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found various problem and finally i've solved all. 
First of all it's necessary to encoding URL adding:

```
myURL = [myURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then, inside original (and actual) TFHPPLE code (for exactly XPathQuery.m) parsing phase going to crash 'cause any time nodeContent and Raw are NIL.
So, to solve this crash I've changed

```
[resultForNode setObject:currentNodeContent forKey:@"nodeContent"];
```

with (ATTENTION FOR BOTH ROWS [resultForNode...:

```
if (currentNodeContent != nil)
   [resultForNode setObject:currentNodeContent forKey:@"nodeContent"];
```

and:

```
[resultForNode setObject:rawContent forKey:@"raw"];
```

with:

```
if (rawContent != nil)
      [resultForNode setObject:rawContent forKey:@"raw"];
```

I want to remember that, 'cause the harder html code used by google, i decide to use these xpathqueries:

```
...
        NSArray *elementsImages = [NSArray new];
        NSArray *elementsPrices = [NSArray new];
        elementsImages = [xpath searchWithXPathQuery:@"//html//*[@class=\"psliimg\"]"];
        elementsPrices = [xpath searchWithXPathQuery:@"//html//*[@class=\"psliprice\"]"];
...
```

Another inconvenience is when you decide to use a for or while cycle to retrieve various html pages, in fact if you use:

```
NSData *htmlData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURL]];
```

initWithContenctsOfURL many times during the cycle cannot get correctly page (and debug console write the famous UNABLE TO PARSE )so I've decide to change it with:

```
// Send a synchronous request
NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURL]];
NSURLResponse * response = nil;
NSError * error = nil;
NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                          returningResponse:&response
                                                      error:&error];

if (error == nil)
{
    // Parse data here
}
```

And if you don't want to waiting this cycle 'cause it's maded by syncronous NSURLRequests try to call parent method with (and your viewcontroller don't freeze waiting for parser):

```
_dispatch_queue_t *queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
                    dispatch_async( _queue, // now i call my google shopping parser cycle
                    ^{
                        [self GShoppingParser];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the below line

```
NSData *htmlData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURL]];
```

to

```
NSData *Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURL]];
```

and also the below line

```
TFHpple *xpath = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];
```

to

```
TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];
```

Let me know if this helps else there is one more line that you may need to change in your code.

happy coding!

Comment: What should change by changing the name of a variable of type NSData or change the name of the parser variable? If you want to know the result is obviously zero, nothing has changed.